# Docker Compose: How to specify path to docker file while building as if in different directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

`docker build -t test2 -f tests/low_conviction_integration/Dockerfile .`

If I need to copy a file from a directory ABOVE my Dockerfile, I can accomplish it by calling

`docker build -t image_name -f path_to_docker_file/Dockerfile .`

from that ABOVE directory

How can I accomplish the same behavior with docker-compose?  I want docker-compose to exist in same directory as Dockerfile, to build with Dockerfile, but to ultimately call it as if it was in ABOVE directory, so that I can copy the correct file.  I tried

`docker-compose -f path_to_docker_file_and_compose/docker-compose.yml up`

from ABOVE directory, but when building from the Dockefile, it complains the files in ABOVE directory are not there to copy when building (which means it is running the docker build from the same directory as the Dockerfile.  I need it to run the build from the ABOVE directory).

Answer (score 56):

This can be done like this, add `build` in docker-compose.yml and run the build from ABOVE directory:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  your_service:
    build: # "context" and "dockerfile" fields have to be under "build"
      context: .
      dockerfile: <Below_Directory>/Dockerfile
```

Comment: `build > context`: relative to docker-compose command running directory.  `build > dockerfile` : relative to `build > context` directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can add your subdirectory in the context. Let's say you have the docker file inside a subdirectory `docker`, the context should be like the below.

```
version: '3'

services:

  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: ./php.dockerfile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
services:
  service-name:
    build:
      context: ../app
      dockerfile: ../docker/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Best and simplest answer!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `-p` flag

```
Usage:
  docker-compose [-f <arg>...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
  docker-compose -h|--help

Options:
  -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file (default: docker-compose.yml)
  -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)
```