# Docker files to docker compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

Im new at docker. I am making a java sockets music server and i have 2 files. Client.java and Server.java. Both are in separate containers. To mention, i run both services in command line

**Docker files**

```
FROM java:8
COPY Server.java /
RUN javac Server.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Server"]
```

```
FROM java:8
COPY Client.java /
RUN javac Client.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Client"]
```

i create also a **network** for these two to communicate.

```
docker network create client_server_network
```

and i run the images as follows:

```
docker run --env SERVER_HOST_ENV=server --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it server

docker run --network client_server_network -it clientimage
```

Now i want to create a docker compose file with those two Dockerfiles and the network. This is what i have done so far:

```
version:'3'
services:
  client:
    image: java:8
    ports:
      -25000:25000
    network:
      default:
        name: client_server_network  
    

  server:
    image: java:8
    ports:
      -25000:25000
    environment:
      -SERVER_HOST_ENV=server 
    network:
```

My question is how to add the common network in both services. Also is the way i write my docker compose file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code, by default both container is added to network named net and it must provide in the last line also

```
version:'3'
services:
  client:
    image: java:8
    ports:
      - 25000:25000
    networks:
      - client_server_network  
    

  server:
    image: java:8
    ports:
      - 25000:25000
    environment:
      - "SERVER_HOST_ENV=server" 
    networks:
      - client_server_network
networks:
  client_server_network:
```

Note that the network should be specified commonly at last in the same level of services and version. As indenting is a main factor in docker-compose. if it is incorrectly indent may shows error.

Comment: Thanks,thats seems to be very close. In the last line ```net:``` i should write my network name? like ```net: client_server_network```

Comment: @william12  Yes bro, you have to change where ever net is specified to client_server_network, ex: both in the client and server section and in the last also

Comment: this would just run two java containers though, not OPs containers, no? I think OP needs to build the two with `docker build -t JServer .` and then have `image: JServer` in the `docker-compose` (same for the client)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  `client` and `server` will be usable as host names by these two containers.

This behavior is described further in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  If you don't declare top-level `networks:`, Compose creates a network called `default`, and if you don't declare `networks:` on a given service, Compose attaches it to that `default` network.

A functional translation of your two `docker run` commands would look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
# Compose creates `networks: { default: }` on its own; you do not need
# top-level `networks:`
services:
  server: # <-- this name is usable as a host name
    image: server
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST_ENV=server
    # Automatically on `networks: [default]`
  client:
    image: clientimage
```

Comment: with ```image: clientimage``` you mean the dockerfile?

Comment: You have to build the image first with `docker build -t <nameOfTheImage> .`! notice the `.` here, which refers to the current directory (so you need to run this command in the directory where the dockerfile is located). Then you can use this image name in your `docker-compose`. (you need to build both the client image and the server image)
OR you can specify the dockerfile [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563854/9903391)

Comment: In your example you `docker run ... clientimage`; it's the same image name.  You can also configure Compose to [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) the image itself.